# github integration workflow: what happened when contributor push changes to the "blessed repository"?

Tags: git, github

Integration workflow described there: 
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Distributed-Git-Distributed-Workflows

[image]

I do not understand one thing: what prevents contributors to do not push commits to the "blessed" repository directly? Do we have there any automation tool which that can "forward" commits pushed to the "blessed" to the "integration manager"? Or this can be regulated only by adminstrative decisions?

Answer (score 2):

> what prevents contributors to do not push commits to the "blessed" repository directly?

There are many ways to prevent that. `gitolite` tool can protect repositories that are available over ssh. Web-based development environments (all those github, gitlab, pagure, etc.) have their own permission management. Finally, there is a simple trick — make the blessed repository private for the integration manager but publish it read-only for everyone else in the team.

> Do we have there any automation tool which that can "forward" commits pushed to the "blessed" to the "integration manager"?

Can be implemented in any way. Git pull request, or GitHub pull request, or anything.